# Are Flash Pixel Bender filters a widely used feature?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, pixel-bender

I haven't seen many Flash games on facebook or other applications really utilize it yet (or appear to utilize it).

Are there some good professional examples of its use?

Is pixel bender just too slow for practical use on today's web hardware?  I read that Flash will fallback to interpreted mode on older Macs (PowerPC), for example, but is that a deal killer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used them for games and websites of motion picures. For example the official site of Harry Potter 7, Part I. And also for some promotional games for Macgruber, and for an AIR app that promoted the movie Terminator Salvation.

They work great, and in many cases can be significantly faster than doing the same effects in another way. But have a very specific use case. I think one of the main reasons you see so little of them is the programming of new shaders requires skills most AS developer do not have. Its hard, and its entirely procedural.

So I cannot account for their being widely used, but theya re definitely a good feature that is production ready.

Comment: +1 hard - yep. I've attempted a few simple shaders, but anything "interesting" was ... elusive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "interpreted mode", but even though they are very similar to pixel shaders, pixel bender filters [do not run on the GPU in Flash Player 10](http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=822). This is primarily to ensure consistency between platforms. This will however change with the introduction of version 11 that supports proper hardware accelerated 3D and can use pixel bender filters for pixel shaders.

As for how common they are it is hard to say, they do require some effort to make as they're made in a separate program. Speedwise they are orders of magnitude faster than looping over individual pixels using actionscript.